# Spreading data from a column with class and variable intermixed

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset in SAS in the following format

```
value   animal
---------------
NA       Felidae
5        Lion
3        Cat
NA       Canidae
1        Dog
2        Wolf
```

I would like to transform this into the following, using either SAS directly, or `proc sql;`

```
group    value  animal
----------------------
Felidae    5     Lion
Felidae    3     Cat
Canidae    1     Dog
Canidae    2     Wolf
```

My first through was to peek at entries further down the list when `value == NA`, until we reach another NA. Then we label all the animals in-between with the animal that had the first `NA`. I would be familiar doing this in python or R, but I'm quite new to SAS and SQL. Of course, I'm aiming to do this as generally as possible without any hard-codings :)

Thanks!

Comment: why value 5 in first table assign to Lion and in second table assign to Cat?

Comment: @AlexeySigida Stupid mistake by me, thanks! Corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data step using `retain` statement:

```
data want;
   set have;
   retain group;
   if value = . then group=animal;
   else output;
run;
```

Output:

```
+-------+--------+---------+
| value | animal |  group  |
+-------+--------+---------+
|     5 | Lion   | Felidae |
|     3 | Cat    | Felidae |
|     1 | Dog    | Canidae |
|     2 | Wolf   | Canidae |
+-------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: I did not know about the keyword retain, amazing! Thank you so much for your help!